# JavaFX - Updating size of BorderPane after modifying size of child node

Tags: java, javafx

I have a BorderPane with a Canvas in its center and I want the BorderPane to always wrap around the canvas when I change the canvas's size. Take for example this code:

```
public class Test extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(10, 10);
        root.setCenter(canvas);

        Scene s = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();

        canvas.setWidth(100);
        canvas.setHeight(100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
```

I want the BorderPane to change its size after I call the setWidth and setHeight methods on canvas, but it just stays the same size as if the canvas was still (10,10) big. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `BorderPane` is the root of your applications `Scene`. The `Scene`s root container will not (at least not automatically) grow larger that its containing `Scene`.

Look at this example application:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(0, 0);
        Button button = new Button("test");
        button.setOnAction(ev -> {
            canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() + 10);
            canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() + 10);
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        });

        BorderPane canvasBorderPane = new BorderPane(canvas);
        canvasBorderPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        canvasBorderPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, new CornerRadii(0), Insets.EMPTY)));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(canvasBorderPane);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, new CornerRadii(0), Insets.EMPTY)));
        root.setBottom(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I stacked two `BorderPane`s together and put the `Canvas` on the innermost, applied some background colors so you can see what is happening.

Comment: Thank you, your effort is appreciated. In the end I just used the Stage class's sizeToScene() method and it fixed my problem.

Comment: If this answers your question, then please mark the answer accordingly ;-)